# Magento category URL redirecting to other product url

Tags: magento

I have a category whose URL key is **toys**, which was accidentally also the URL key for a product. Therefore everytime I visited toys.html, It was redirected to the product page and not the category one.

Now, I have changed the product URL to something else, but still the category page redirects to the product page only. Please tell me how to solve this issue.

This is the category [LINK](http://www.eyaas.com/children-eyases/toys.html)

**UPDATE** :- When i renamed the toys category to toys-arena, it started working. So I have renamed the URL using toys-arena.html

Comment: I did that. But it didnt helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the magento admin area, Catalog -> URL Rewrites

you can then search for you product or category url, and edit or delete them. you can delete any old reqrites you no longer want to use.